# Responsive d3 bubble chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to implement a responsive d3 bubble chart that updates its container svg (and the nodes it contains) while the page is being resized (kinda like this shows: http://jsfiddle.net/63K4n/)

But instead of just shrinking the nodes down to a size that fits the screen, I want to increase the height of the container as the width is being decreased to create the additional space necessary for the nodes to fall into without being shrunk.

I played with updating the last few lines of the fiddle to this...

```
chart.attr("width", targetWidth);
chart.attr("height", Math.round(921600/targetWidth)); //was targetWidth/aspectRatio
```

(where 921,600 was simply the diameter [960] squared - i.e. the total required space)

But of course although this increases the height of the container correctly, the nodes don't exploit the new space - that's what I'm struggling to figure out - how to change the shape of the bubble chart to fit the new space (if that's even possible!)

If not possible with a standard bubble chart, I'd also be happy to try a static force layout (e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139) combined with a resizable example like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3355967.  Again the problem is finding a way to reshape the nodes to within the confines of their new container, so I'm guessing I'd have to adapt collision detection to account for the svg container boundaries.  And with all that going on I'm pretty sure there'd be a decent lag on a mobile device while you're waiting for the force layout to tick its way to something I can update the page with.

Sorry if that's all a little vague, but I'm really just hoping someone has a general suggestion on an appropriate way to tackle the problem.  Huge thanks for any thoughts at all!

Answer (score 0):

When a resize event occurs call a function with:

```
d3.selectAll('#chart svg').remove()
```

to clear the current chart then pass the new height/size info into a update function that redraws the chart.  Its kinda hard to give you a more specific answer without your code and where you're stuck...but that's generally how I redraw my D3 stuff when data or other groovy things change.

Ok, based on the two fiddles/code pens it looks like

```
var diameter = 500, // <---Feed new variable here
format = d3.format(",d"),
color = d3.scale.category20c();

var width = 450, height = 2000;

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
   .sort(null)
   .size([diameter, diameter])
   .padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("viewBox","0 0 500 500") //<----and Here
   .attr("width", diameter)
   .attr("height", diameter)
   .attr("class", "bubble");
```

Changing the diameter and the veiwBox attribute makes everything shrink in the proper proportion. Sorry if i miss understood the question, and if I'm still not getting it. But a redraw function that feeds in new data there based on a change in window should work.

Also, just changing the

```
var height = XXX
```

doesn't look like its changing the height, since the

```
.attr('width',diameter)
```

is using diameter instead of height.

Anyway, I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but if I do that with the bubble chart approach I'd just end up with the same issue of having my nodes shrunk to fit the smaller screen size (as happens in http://jsfiddle.net/63K4n/).  Whereas if I did it with the force layout approach I'd have to integrate some kind of bound collision detection like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492 (with the existing collision detection between nodes) which would end up responding badly on mobile devices (and firefox) - it's not enough to just update the container and redraw the layout - the nodes just overspill the bounds of the container.

Comment: a quick example on the bubble chart to show what I'm talking about: http://codepen.io/d3wannabe/pen/rOjEEB.  I've given plenty of height (2000px) to account for the relatively short width (450), but obviously the bubbles don't automatically flow into the new space - I need to find a way to shape the chart to the new dimensions

Comment: Sorry I miss understood the question (and still might be), anyway, I've edited my answer...

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks again for the efforts here, but I don't want to shrink the nodes in the bubble chart.  I'm looking for a way to reposition them using the available space in the container (in the codepen I posted, that space is shown at the bottom of the container, but of course I haven't been able to get the nodes that are cut off horizontally to appear below).  So I'm trying to change the shape of the bubble chart (from something with an equal width/height to something with a bigger height).  Thanks.

Comment: Ohhhh, I finally get it....Sorry I wasn't able to point you in the right direction.